# Are uncle/ommer blocks still possible after the merge?

Tags: blockchain, blocks, uncle-blocks

Uncle blocks were produced before the merge when two miners found a solution at the same time and following blocks were appended to only one of them. So my question is, are uncle/ommer blocks still possible after the merge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the post-merge PoS Ethereum, validators will be pre-selected to validate blocks, which means that no more than one validator will be validating a block at a time. Hence, there are no uncle (ommer) blocks created. Also, the ommer field in the block header (from PoW Ethereum) will be empty as it's unused and irrelevant in post-merge PoS Ethereum.

See: [Block header structure change under Proof of Stake?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8571/block-header-structure-change-under-proof-of-stake/129809#129809)