# PoS: What comes instead of NewBlock(0x07) and NewBlockHashes(0x01)?

Tags: proof-of-stake

I see in https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3675#devp2p that NewBlock and NewBlockHashes are deprecated, but can't see what comes instead to propagate blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `NewBlock` and `NewBlockHashes` are discarded because of the change in the consensus mechanisms from PoW to PoS and they are are no longer used or relevant in PoS, as `NewBlock` and `NewBlockHashes` are part of the two part process in validating block headers in PoW during block propagation.

See:

https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/caps/eth.md

[Block header structure change under the Merge to Proof of Stake?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8571/block-header-structure-change-under-the-merge-to-proof-of-stake)

Comment: I know the reason they were discarded, I'm asking what messages come instead.

Comment: According to EIP-3675, deprecated block fields are replaced with constant values in PoS to ensure the block format remains backwards compatible. Preserving the block format aids existing smart contracts and services in providing uninterrupted service during and after this transition. See: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3675

Comment: I'm not asking about fields. What are the messages that are used to propagate a new block?